# continuous mode on llvm

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

Пытаюсь активировать режим continuous mode в llvm, судя по комментариям из коммита,следующие команды должны работать:

1. clang++-13 -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -mllvm -runtime-counter-relocation=true -o %t.exe %s
2. LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="%c%t.profraw" %t.exe
3. llvm-profdata show --counts --all-functions %t.profraw

На 3 команде выдает ошибку - Unsupported instrumentation profile format version
Не могу понять, что не так, буду благодарен за любую помощь!
Ссылка на коммит: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/d3db13af7e5c01632fbf28149a2d4f9c4841aeba
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, и не используйте скриншоты для текстовой информации.

Comment: ¿А llvm-profdata соответствует clang++-13? ¿Может там где-нибудь завалялся llvm-profdata-13 или что-то подобное?